# how to config apache jmeter 2.6 oauth 2.0

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, jmeter

I need to perform tests using jmeter for an oauth 2.0 secured API. I have found the following plugin

http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-oauth/

I managed to successfully install it but now I am stuck with actually writing the tests. The documentation is missing....does anyone have a clue on how to actually use the plugin ?

Thanks.

Comment: [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask): it's a good idea to thanks for the help if you ask for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your problem in JMeter OAuth Sampler usage - or in OAuth protocol testing strategy itself?

What's wrong with [JMeter OAuth Sampler guide](http://jmeter-oauth.googlecode.com/files/JMeter%20OAuth%20Sampler.pdf) on plugin's site?

Beware only that sampler could not work or work not properly with Jmeter versions 2.5.x/2.6 - see [related issue](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-oauth/issues/detail?id=3).
You can also use [OAuth Test Client](http://term.ie/oauth/example/client.php) for additional verification.

**UPDATED:**

Again, use [OAuth Test Client](http://term.ie/oauth/example/client.php) with any HTTP analyzer ([HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/) is good one) to study interaction using OAuth protocol - in this case with [OAuth Test Server](http://term.ie/oauth/example/index.php).

[Here](http://term.ie/oauth/example/index.php) you'll find description of all the steps of interaction that are easily mapped onto sampler on the picture in JMeter OAuth Sampler guide:

1. **Getting a Request Token** ("Authentication" sampler on the picture).
   Here you have to extract `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` from
   successfull response to use further in OAuth Sampler:

   `oauth_token=requestkey&oauth_token_secret=requestsecret`

   Corresponding extractors are displayed as children of Authentication
   sampler.
2. **Getting an Access Token** ("Token Validation")
3. **Get Data** ("Get Data" OAuth Sampler on the picture).

Find protocol flow and specification [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-23#section-1.2).

Here `${oauth_token}` and `${token_secret}` are extracted from the 1st sampler's response.

Comment: The image that is shown is not really helpful. It is the final configuration but does not show how to get there.