# JMeter: Can't sign in to the app that uses Google Auth

Tags: jmeter

I wanna create a test in JMeter for an web app that use google auth as a login.
So basically user sees the app login button on login page, clicks it --> navigates to google login page where he should set an email, a password, and click Sign In button.
I have stucked on "Sign In" step that is the following post request:
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth

all parameters are easy to extract except for "bgresponse".
when user navigates to google sign in page, bgresponse value = js_disabled that is not default and cannot be used for the post request.
it is set with a real value when user hits Sign in button.

thus, I can't extract the correct bgresponse value value as a post processor of the request that leads to google sign in page.

Any ideas how can I sign in to google via JMeter?
Please help.

TIA
Anna

Answer (score 0):

Google supports oauth 2.0
https://developers.google.com/accounts/

so I think you can expand your question to JMeter and oauth 2.0
Here are a few resources:
https://malalanayake.wordpress.com/tag/oauth-2-0/
[how to config apache jmeter 2.6 oauth 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699611/how-to-config-apache-jmeter-2-6-oauth-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

I think than you can use [WebDriver Sampler](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) available via [plugin](http://www.jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) (you'll need WebDriver Set). This extension allows Selenium tests to be executed from JMeter and you can launch a real browser to perform Google authentication and obtain permanent OAuth token from callback page.

You won't be able to do any performance testing with the WebDriver Sampler (don't attempt to use it with more than 1 thread), but it'll be quite enough for successful OAuth 3-step process.